Adobe sign certificate validation
We have a webhook endpoint which adobe calls each time subscribed event occurs.
Adobe offers two way SSL authentication option where we can upload certificate in .p12 format on their portal and then it will use provided certificate in subsequent request on our endpoint.
My questions are:
how can I validate this certificate on my side?
Is there any build in tools?
Best practices ?
Do I need additional configuration for my endpoint to accept certificates?
we are using .NET framework 4.7
what am I going to do:
var clientCert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;
if (clientCert != null && clientCert.IsPresent)
{
    var subject = clientCert.Subject;
    var issuer = clientCert.Issuer;
    var serialNumber = clientCert.SerialNumber;
    var validFrom = clientCert.ValidFrom;
    var validUntil = clientCert.ValidUntil;

    // validate properties
}

Thank you!
EDIT:
var clientCert = HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate;

returned NULL. Need to find other ways of getting certificate from request.

The initial thing to do would be to compare the Thumbprint of the Certificate is the one you expect to get here. If you want to check the validity of the certificate beyond that is debatable. You uploaded the cert for authentication and got it back. Does it matter if its valid in this context like its not expired or so?

Hi Ralf, I do not think it is important to check expiry of certificate. My main goal is that only adobe should be able to make calls to my endpoint. Honestly do not know what "Thumbprint of the Certificate" is cause my knowledge about certificates are limited but it seems some kind of unique identified.  So if someone makes call with some certificate its Thumbprint will be different right ?

The thumbprint is a hash of the contained data so you don't need the individual data for a check. And here thumbprint is just a property of your clientcert variable see the docs even if just marginal helpful. So store the certificate or just the thumbprint when you upload the cert and then compare the thumbprints in your endpoint for authentication.
